# hugo: static site not fully generated in public dir

Tags: hugo, hugo-theme

I'm new to hugo. I'm trying to generate the static version of my site.

- I can run `hugo server` without any issue, the site shows up correctly in the browser.
- But when I run `hugo`, the site shows up but without any of the CSS style.

The test site is [here](https://github.com/erwanm/hugoattempt). What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

(In case anyone has the same confusion as me; answer from [here](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/static-site-generated-but-without-the-expected-style/40945))

This is actually expected, the static site generated with `hugo` can only be viewed directly on the target site, not locally in the browser. One should simply use `hugo server` to view the site locally.